# Dynamically add Icons to titlebar Maui

Tags: icons, maui, titlebar

Im creating an App where I want have multiple icons in my titlebar (they should be clickable). One Icon should be on the Left of the title text like so (this icon is static and will not change):

[image]

The other Icons should be on the right (these icons should be dynamic, as they will be used to alert the user if anything important happens):

[image]

I'm using a simple shell, so no Navigationpage, thus I don't think `<NavigationPage.Titleview>` can be used in this case. Is there any way to achieve something like this in Maui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the shell title view as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662562/10404482), it is pointing to Xamarin documentation but it is also valid for MAUI.

In your case you will have something like this inside your `AppShell.xaml` :

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="auto,*,auto">
        <Label Text="Title" BackgroundColor="Red"></Label>
        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="2">
            <Label Text="Icon" BackgroundColor="Red"></Label>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Which look like this (very trendy design) :

[image: Title view result]

How to update the icons can be done by [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0) or creating directly the object from C# :

```
        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="2" x:Name="IconsContainer">
            <Label Text="Icon" BackgroundColor="Red" IsVisible="{Binding Icon1Visible}"></Label>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
```

And in the C# :

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public bool Icon1Visible { get; set; } = false;

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // An object containing the binding data
        BindingContext = this;

        // Directly create a new icon
        AddIcon();

        // Show an icon through binding
        ShowIcon();
    }

    public void ShowIcon()
    {
        Icon1Visible = true;
    }

    public void AddIcon()
    {
        var icon = new Label();
        icon.Text = "And another one";
        IconsContainer.Children.Add(icon);
    }
}
```

To get whenever you want to update the icons I would go with [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection) and either pass directly a view model to bind the icons on or using events.